# How to install rabbitmq and erlang on centOS without root user?

Tags: linux, installation, centos

Can anyone help me with installation?
I have install virtualEnv and trying to install both of these. but not sure it is correct or not.

Comment: You should have a look  or ask your question in [Unix&Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) **or** [superuser](http://superuser.com/)

Comment: I cant access both the sites at my place

Comment: You should sign in to both

Comment: Did my solution work for you?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old version, but it worked for me on a different Linux build (Mate OS). Follow the steps in this blog [post](https://deepkrish.wordpress.com/) which I have simplified below.

**Download the below**

[ERLANG from OTP R16B03-1 Source File](http://www.erlang.org/download/otp_src_R16B03-1.tar.gz)

[RabbitMQ from RabbitMQ Server.tar.gz](http://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-server/v3.2.3/rabbitmq-server-3.2.3.tar.gz)

**Installing Erlang**

1. Extract the ERLANG file
2. `cd` to source folder
3. run `$ configure`
4. run `$ make`
5. Open `Makefile` and change `/Users/deepkrish/Application/erlang` to a suitable directory
   The line you are looking for is the below: 
   `# prefix from configure, default is /usr/local (must be an absolute path)   prefix = /Users/deepkrish/Application/erlang`
6. Run `$ make install` 
   Once Erlang is installed non root user add the erlang/bin to PATH in `.bash_profile` like below: 
   `export ERLANG=”/Users/deepkrish/Application/erlang/bin”` 
   `export PATH=${ERLANG}:${PATH}`
7. Now execute the profile by running `$ source .bash_profile” or log off and login again.
8. Check `$ erl -version` This should give you the below: 
   `Erlang (SMP,ASYNC_THREADS,HIPE) (BEAM) emulator version 5.10.4`

**Installing RabbitMQ**

1. Untar the RabbitMQ.tar file and `$ cd` to the extracted folder

run `$ make`
2. This should create a scripts folder. Now change into that. `$ cd scripts`

3. Now change the below in the `rabbitmq-defaults` file. This will change where we run and log rabbitMQ. You can change it to the folder you want to run RabbitMQ from as below

`### next line potentially updated in package install steps SYS_PREFIX=~/Application/RabbitMQ`

4. Save and close the file
   Now create a directory `mkdir -p ../etc/rabbitmq` Note that if you don't have access to the /etc directory you can also change it to somewhere else.
5. `./rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management`
6. Start rabbitmq server `$ ./rabbitmq-server &`

I use the below script file to start RabbitMQ server whenever I log on.

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /home/myusername/myproject/RabbitMQ/rabbitmq-server-3.2.3/scripts
export ERLANG="/home/myusername/myproject/RabbitMQ/erlang/bin"
export PATH=${ERLANG}:${PATH}
./rabbitmq-server &
```